# Understand code from string using Regex or something - Js

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I wanted to run a string replace function on a piece of code and make sure that all the strings in the code is intact and unchanged using javascript. For example if I have a code like below:

```
var a = "I am ok";

if (a == "I am ok") {
   alert("That's great to know");
}
```

Now, I want to run a string replace on this code block. But it should only effect the code part of it. Not the strings which are in double quotes. Can this be done using regex or any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### AST

To avoid any chance of error in code manipulation using an [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) type solution is best. One example implementation is in [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) which is a JavaScript parser, minifier, compressor or beautifier toolkit.

### RegEx

Alternatively if an AST is over the top  for your specific task you can use RegEx.

But do you have to contend with comments too?

The process might look like this:

1. Use a carefully formed regex to **split** the JavaScript code string based on these in this order:

   - comment blocks
   - comment lines
   - quoted strings both single and double quotes (remembering to contend with escaping of characters).
2. Iterate though the split components. If string (beings with `"` or `'`) or comment (begins with `//` or `/*`) ignore, otherwise run your replacement.
3. (and the simple part) join array of strings back together.

Comment: [Acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) seems to be the perfect tool to parse javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to place the function code in a string variable, run a normal regex operation over that string, and then convert it to a function afterwards with:

```
var func = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
```

EDIT: Use regex to exclude the text between double quotes if you need to.